# Unable to open a task form directly in the browser

Tags: 2010, workflow, infopath, form, tasks

**Environment :** Sharepoint 2010

I have a workflow on a list that sends a task to a user.
The form of this task is not compatible with any browser.
Also by mail, it's impossible to open it.

**I have these errors when I open the task :**

- with Chrome : "This form cannot be opened in the browser. To open this form, use Microsoft InfoPath."
- with Internet Explorer : "The specified form template could not be found, or is not compatible with rendering in the browser. It might need to be republished as a browser-enabled form."
- with Outlook : "Outlook cannot open a new form, the form contains schema validation errors."

**What I did to get that :**

I've just added a field in the task directly in the workflow (using the data collect command). The task was already here and worked well before that.

When I did the change, my workflow ask me to update the task form with InfoPath (I just never had to do stuff with InfoPath). If i hadn't done that, I couldn't have publish my workflow.
Then I did that. And since, there's a problem with the opening of the task form on any browser.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it.

It's as simple as that : In SharePoint Designer, on my workflow page, I just deleted my form from the form block (see below). And when I have published my workflow, my form was recreated but it works everywhere.

[image]

- To delete it, just select it, and in the ribbon you can click on the delete button.

Hope it helps.